# Change selected tab after receiving Push Notification

Tags: iphone, ios, delegates, push-notification, uitabbar

I'm wanting to change the tab that is open when the app is opened from a push notification.

At the moment, I have the app registering the notification in the app delegate and running a method in the 1st view controller:

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

NSLog(@"didReceiveRemoteNotification");self.apstype = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];self.apstype = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"apstype"]];

    // Add the tab bar controller's current view as a subview of the window
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];

    HomeTab_Main *controller = [HomeTab_Main alloc];
    [controller receivedNotification];

    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive){
        NSLog(@"UIApplicationStateActive");
    } else if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground){
        NSLog(@"UIApplicationStateBackground");
    } else if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive){
        NSLog(@"UIApplicationStateInactive");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"else");
    }
}
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UINavigationBar *navigationBarProxy = [UINavigationBar appearance];
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
        UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ge_navigationBar.png"];
        [navigationBarProxy setBackgroundImage:backgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    } else if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
        UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ge_navigationBar~ipad.png"];
        [navigationBarProxy setBackgroundImage:backgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    }

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

    UIColor *tintColour = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.000 green:0.600 blue:0.765 alpha:1];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:tintColour];

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1.0],
      UITextAttributeTextColor, [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.8], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor, [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, -1)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset, [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-Bold" size:0.0], UITextAttributeFont, nil]];

    return YES;
}
```

**HomeTab_Main.m**

```
- (void)receivedNotification
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSLog(@"%@", appDelegate.apstype);
    if([appDelegate.apstype isEqualToString:@"inbox"]){
        NSLog(@"goToTab");
        [self performSelector:@selector(goToTab) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
    }
}

- (void)goToTab
{    
    NSLog(@"Go to tab");
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"1 new message" message:@"click to read" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];

    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2;
}
```

The main issue I'm having is that the alert view is displaying, but the tab isn't changing.
When access the app from a notification, I want to automatically switch to the corresponding tab. Does anyone know how this is possible with any examples?

**Added didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**

Comment: if you remove the alert, does it change the tab?

Comment: hmmm, if you increase the delay here afterDelay:0.1 say to 2 seconds, does it work?

Comment: Nope, had the delay up to 10 seconds... is weird @OmarAbdelhafith

Answer (score 1):

Luc is right, although it's `self.view.window.rootViewController` instead of `self.rootviewcontroller`.
However I don't think it's the perfect solution since the `TabBarController` doesn't always have to be the rootViewController...

Do you have your `TabBarController` in the app delegate/mainwindow or in another viewController?

Try setting the `selectedIndex` within the app delegate or the viewController that holds your TabBarController.

I got this to work in one of my apps using this:

**AppDelegate.m**

```
-(void)showReportTab{
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
}
```

**AppDelegate.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBarController;
```

Comment: sorry Dave! obviously I'm new, I'll keep the code highlighting in mind next time ;)

Answer (score 0):

Can we also get the code from the method `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`? I would like to see how you are creating the tabBarController.

Also try to call `self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2;` in the method `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and check if the correct view controller becomes active.

Comment: adding self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2 errors, saying 'Property 'tabBarController' not found on object type AppDelegate *' @lucwollants

Comment: No Xcode at hand to test it, but it must be something like self.rootviewcontroller then. The AppDelegate has no tabcontroller, but the RootViewController should have one. Also make sure it is not nil (sending to nil is valid in Objective-C)